# NVIDIA X Server power safe mode unavailable

Tags: drivers, nvidia

So I'm having a problem where my NVIDIA X server suddenly doesn't allow me to switch my laptop to the 'Intel (Power Saving Mode)'...

I've been using this laptop for over a year now and have never had such problems. I'm not quite sure how to fix it, I have tried rebooting my system but that didn't seem to work.

If anyone knows of this problem or has ideas on how I could fix this that would be much appreciated, as it would be a pain to have to plug it in always due to fast battery drain.

---

Nvidia X-Server "PRIME Profile" page:

[image: Nvidia X-Server "PRIME Profile" page]

Comment: This appears to be a "feature" of the latest Nvidia driver. What version are you running? What do you see when you type `prime-select` in the terminal?

Comment: @heynnema The output of prime-select is this

`Usage: /usr/bin/prime-select nvidia|intel|on-demand|query`

and I was able to select intel via that....

Also my nvidea x-config version was version 470.103.01 while my nvidea-settings version was version 470.57.01

Comment: Yes. I reinstalled 470 (from 510) and was dismayed to still have the same problem with the Intel Power Saving choice missing. It must be with the nvidia-settings app, as they use the same version in 510 and 470. Glad that the prime-select works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As answered by [heynnema](https://askubuntu.com/users/4272/heynnema), this looks to be an issue with the NVIDIA X Server that can be contoured configuring the Intel profile through terminal with `sudo prime-select intel`.

Comment: Though unfortunately, the Intel option stays grey and can not be selected in the Nvidia X Server Settings app. Even when having switched to Intel mode with prime-select and rebooted, the app shows that Intel is selected but it's greyed out. It can switch to Nvidia modes but never back to Intel mode. Seems to be a bug or Nvidia doesn't want people to use Intel mode…