# Unable to set Nvidia Graphics card to Power Save mode

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, power-management, 22.04

my HP aptop comes with a Nvidia graphics card. I was kind of able to turn it off using `Nvidia Xserver Settings` as seen below in while using 21.10

[image]

Now that I have upgraded to 22.04, the Intel (Power Saving Mode) option is greyed out. I can only select On-Demand and Performance Mode.

It is affecting the laptop's battery backup.

It would be nice to know some method to set it into Power Saving Mode during light work. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1395034/nvidia-x-server-power-safe-mode-unavailable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NVIDIA X Server power safe mode unavailable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1395034/nvidia-x-server-power-safe-mode-unavailable)

Answer (score 3):

This command helped

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

Thanks to

[NVIDIA X Server power safe mode unavailable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1395034/nvidia-x-server-power-safe-mode-unavailable)

Answer (score 0):

This will actually recreate boot image with update-initramfs.
Using AMD GPU is not possible to have CPU only graphics without a restart of the xserver.

```
# prime-select intel
Info: selecting the intel profile
Updating the initramfs. Please wait for the operation to complete:
/W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/ip_discovery.bin for module amdgpu
|W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vega10_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_cap.bin for module amdgpu
\W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_cap.bin for module amdgpu
\W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_0_toc.bin for module amdgpu
-W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes1.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
Done
```